# How to pass variable from one python script to another

Tags: python, wxpython, python-module

my code has this structure

```
class Mapsframe(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        import application

class Example(wx.Frame,listmix.ColumnSorterMixin):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Example, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):

    def onItemSelected(self,event):

        frame = Mapsframe()
```

the `application` is another python scipt that is running and I want to pass some variables that have been created locally inside of `def onItemSelected` to a class inside the python script `application.py`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can add another method to the MapsFrame class that accepts arguments.  Like so:

```
def take_args(arg1, arg2):
  self.arg1 = arg1
  self.arg2 = arg2
```

that way, in your example class, you would just do this:

```
def onItemSelected(self,event):
  arg1 = 'foo';
  arg2 = 'bar';
  frame = Mapsframe()
  frame.take_args(arg1,arg2)
```

Comment: and how to import def take_args inside the script application to take the values arg1,arg2

Comment: I'd need to know a little bit more about the application you're importing.  It would be possible that you could import a settings file that is related to the application, modify that based on the args and then run the app.

Comment: it a python script my mistake with classes and definitions, it is wxpymaps script and i use Mapsframe to display it to a window but i can not pass variables in a class inside application.py

Comment: Okay, so what exactly is it that you're trying to pass? I'm guessing it's this file here?https://github.com/sinapsi/wxpymaps/blob/master/application.py

Comment: in line 672 is this         self.NewPointDialog(coords="38.132329,15.158815") i have change the code a bit and have `coords="38.132329,15.158815"                   lat, lon = coords.split(",")                                    name = ''
description = ''
newMarker = Marker(lat, lon, name, description)
self.markers.append(newMarker)
newMarker.draw(self, self.pdc)`  i just want to take the coords from the other script and these lines afer deleting definitions are inside the class PyMap frame

Comment: It looks like there are classmethods that you can use that will accept the variables you want? I'm a little lost as to your question...can you rephrase?  The way I see it you can just create an instance of whatever class you want inside application.py after you "import application", and if you want it to accept the arguments just put the instantiation of the class inside the 'take_args'method above and you should be fine.  Is there something I'm missing?